# div can not be styled (e.g. background) with external css file

Tags: html, css

My hierarchy is the following:

```
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── main_bkg.jpg
│   └── js
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

In my `index.html`, I have the following code:

```
<body>
<header> ... </header>
<div class="container"></div>
<footer> ... </footer>
</body>
```

In my `main.css` file, I have

```
.container {
    background-image: url('../img/main_bkg.jpg');
}
```

This does not load the image in my index page. However if I change .container to body, then it works. So I think there is no problem with the path of the image.

I tried to use

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Then using css selector `#container`, still no luck.

What did I miss in my steps? Thanks!

Comment: url('../static/img/main_bkg.jpg')

Comment: used to this background-image: url('../../img/main_bkg.jpg');

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: Have you imported the css file in a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL" />` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.container` do not have any `height and width`, so it is not showing background image, while `body` might be having some dimensions.

So add style in css as:

```
.container {
    background-image: url('../img/main_bkg.jpg');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
}
```

Now try it will display the image.

Answer (score 2):

The reference is wrong. It should be:

```
.container {
    background-image: url("../img/main_bkg.jpg");
}
```

Since you have an empty container, the height of `.container` is 0. Try adding a `min-height` or `padding` to see the effect. This might cause issue too. This might help:

```
.container {
  background-image: url("../img/main_bkg.jpg");
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 50px; /* Something */
}
```